# How to create a base class/struct for value objects that validates based on super class values?

Tags: c#, .net-core

this is a problem I'm not sure how to call it or how name the things I want to do but hopefully the code examples can speak for themselves. I come from a PHP background and am learning .NET Core 2.2/3.0. Something I'm running into right now though is how I can avoid some code duplication when creating similar classes. For example I want to create multiple value objects that basically just contain strings, but each value object has different constraints. In most cases however the only constraint differences are in the length.

So in PHP I would do something like this:

```
abstract class Text
{
    abstract public static function maxCharacters(): int;

    protected $value;

    public function __construct(string $text)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($text) > static::maxCharacters()) {
            throw new LengthException(sprintf('Too many characters, the max is %d.', static::maxCharacters()));
        }

        $this->value = $text;
    }

    public function value(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

class Name extends Text
{
    public static function maxCharacters(): int
    {
        return 50;
    }
}

class Description extends Text
{
    public static function maxCharacters(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

It's not the best example of inheritance, but the goal is to illustrate the point in that I would like to have 1 place where I can put my validation logic, and then in the subclass only have to define the parameters of the validation and not the actual logic to perform the validation.

Since we're dealing with value objects here I assume that in C# it would be best to use a (`readonly`) struct. So, without any inheritance, what I ended up with as the C# equivalent is:

```
public readonly struct Name
{
    private const int MAX_CHARACTERS = 50;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.Value; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > Name.MAX_CHARACTERS)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Too many characters, the max is {0}.", Name.MAX_CHARACTERS));
            }

            this.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public Name(string name) => this.Value = name;
}

public readonly struct Description
{
    private const int MAX_CHARACTERS = 1000;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.Value; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > Description.MAX_CHARACTERS)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Too many characters, the max is {0}.", Description.MAX_CHARACTERS));
            }

            this.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public Description(string description) => this.Value = description;
}
```

But as you can see without inheritance that's a lot of copy/paste, and copy/paste is something I prefer to avoid. The only alternative I could think of is to create a separate `TextValidator` class or something that I can call from the `set` to which I would only have to pass the max number of characters, but that would still leave me with more copy/paste than I'd prefer.

How would you write something like this in C# with as little copy/paste as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've got the basics of inheritance understood in your PHP example; I'd just suggest doing a bit of reading on [the syntax in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance).

For what it's worth, the following would do the trick:

```
public abstract class Text{
    public string Value { get; }
    public Text(string val) {
        if (val.Length > MAX) throw new Exception();
        Value = val;
    }
    protected abstract int MAX{get;}
}
public class Name : Text{
    public Name(string val): base(val) { }
    protected override int MAX => 50;
}
public class Description : Text
{
    public Description(string val) : base(val) { }
    protected override int MAX => 1000;
}
```

I'll also add a footnote to say be careful calling abstract methods/properties from a class constructor (which is what I'm doing here). If, for example, the value of MAX is a computed value which depends on the object already having been initialized, you could run into some issues. In this case though, it won't be a problem.